# Hung Task in VM - Cant reboot

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a hung task in a VM that I think would normally require a REISUB Syskey style reboot, which is not available in the Google Dev Console. Is there another way? It doesn't seem that the reboot command via the Developer Console is doing anything either.  This is a pretty major issue - Not sure how to recover.

```
[505440.360052] INFO: task first-boot:21323 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[505440.361344] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[505440.362581] first-boot      D ffff88006c813780     0 21323  21314 0x00000000
[505440.362585]  ffff880037095690 0000000000000086 ffff88006748a180 ffffffff8160d020
[505440.362587]  0000000000013780 ffff8800697fbfd8 ffff8800697fbfd8 ffff880037095690
[505440.362590]  0000000000000246 ffffffff8134fd89 ffff88006cbdf4a8 ffff8800247705f8
[505440.362592] Call Trace:
[505440.362599]  [<ffffffff8134fd89>] ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x9/0x25
[505440.362608]  [<ffffffffa0098660>] ? do_get_write_access+0x1ad/0x36a [jbd2]
[505440.362612]  [<ffffffff8105fcfd>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x2a/0x2a
[505440.362618]  [<ffffffffa00b15b4>] ? ext4_dirty_inode+0x2a/0x45 [ext4]
[505440.362620]  [<ffffffffa0098911>] ? jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x21/0x38 [jbd2]
[505440.362626]  [<ffffffffa00d1263>] ? __ext4_journal_get_write_access+0x4f/0x5e [ext4]
[505440.362631]  [<ffffffffa00afb5e>] ? ext4_reserve_inode_write+0x37/0x7a [ext4]
[505440.362634]  [<ffffffffa00afc09>] ? ext4_mark_inode_dirty+0x68/0x1da [ext4]
[505440.362638]  [<ffffffffa00b159e>] ? ext4_dirty_inode+0x14/0x45 [ext4]
[505440.362643]  [<ffffffffa00c66d8>] ? ext4_journal_start_sb+0x139/0x14f [ext4]
[505440.362647]  [<ffffffffa00b15b4>] ? ext4_dirty_inode+0x2a/0x45 [ext4]
[505440.362650]  [<ffffffffa00b158a>] ? ext4_evict_inode+0x2af/0x2af [ext4]
[505440.362654]  [<ffffffff811174b3>] ? __mark_inode_dirty+0x22/0x17a
[505440.362657]  [<ffffffffa00b006d>] ? ext4_setattr+0x2f2/0x377 [ext4]
[505440.362660]  [<ffffffff8104b2a6>] ? current_fs_time+0x31/0x37
[505440.362662]  [<ffffffff8110e393>] ? notify_change+0x1cb/0x293
[505440.362665]  [<ffffffff81036628>] ? should_resched+0x5/0x23
[505440.362668]  [<ffffffff810f94f8>] ? do_truncate+0x68/0x86
[505440.362669]  [<ffffffff810f91ca>] ? __dentry_open+0x1cd/0x2c2
[505440.362672]  [<ffffffff811056b7>] ? do_last+0x4b9/0x58d
[505440.362674]  [<ffffffff81105d83>] ? path_openat+0xce/0x33a
[505440.362676]  [<ffffffff810ce865>] ? pte_offset_kernel+0x16/0x35
[505440.362678]  [<ffffffff811060b1>] ? do_filp_open+0x2a/0x6e
[505440.362680]  [<ffffffff8134ea6c>] ? _cond_resched+0x7/0x1c
[505440.362683]  [<ffffffff811b4589>] ? __strncpy_from_user+0x18/0x48
[505440.362686]  [<ffffffff8110ee37>] ? alloc_fd+0x64/0x109
[505440.362687]  [<ffffffff810fa07d>] ? do_sys_open+0x5e/0xe5
[505440.362690]  [<ffffffff81354d92>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[505440.362692] INFO: task emulator64-x86:21325 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[505440.363880] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[505440.365178] emulator64-x86  D ffff88006c813780     0 21325  21283 0x00000004
[505440.365181]  ffff88003735f610 0000000000000086 0000000000000282 ffff8800374ef8d0
[505440.365183]  0000000000013780 ffff8800373b5fd8 ffff8800373b5fd8 ffff88003735f610
[505440.365185]  0000000000000246 ffffffff8134fd89 ffff88006cbdf4a8 ffff8800247705f8
[505440.365187] Call Trace:
[505440.365190]  [<ffffffff8134fd89>] ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x9/0x25
[505440.365194]  [<ffffffffa0098660>] ? do_get_write_access+0x1ad/0x36a [jbd2]
[505440.365196]  [<ffffffff8105fcfd>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x2a/0x2a
[505440.365200]  [<ffffffffa00b15b4>] ? ext4_dirty_inode+0x2a/0x45 [ext4]
[505440.365203]  [<ffffffffa0098911>] ? jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x21/0x38 [jbd2]
[505440.365208]  [<ffffffffa00d1263>] ? __ext4_journal_get_write_access+0x4f/0x5e [ext4]
[505440.365212]  [<ffffffffa00afb5e>] ? ext4_reserve_inode_write+0x37/0x7a [ext4]
[505440.365216]  [<ffffffffa00afc09>] ? ext4_mark_inode_dirty+0x68/0x1da [ext4]
[505440.365219]  [<ffffffffa00b159e>] ? ext4_dirty_inode+0x14/0x45 [ext4]
[505440.365224]  [<ffffffffa00c66d8>] ? ext4_journal_start_sb+0x139/0x14f [ext4]
[505440.365228]  [<ffffffffa00b15b4>] ? ext4_dirty_inode+0x2a/0x45 [ext4]
[505440.365231]  [<ffffffffa00b158a>] ? ext4_evict_inode+0x2af/0x2af [ext4]
[505440.365234]  [<ffffffff811174b3>] ? __mark_inode_dirty+0x22/0x17a
[505440.365236]  [<ffffffff8110cbbf>] ? touch_atime+0xe7/0x10c
[505440.365239]  [<ffffffff810b6729>] ? generic_file_aio_read+0x570/0x5cf
[505440.365241]  [<ffffffff811056ea>] ? do_last+0x4ec/0x58d
[505440.365243]  [<ffffffff810fa464>] ? do_sync_read+0xb4/0xec
[505440.365245]  [<ffffffff810fab4f>] ? vfs_read+0x9f/0xe6
[505440.365247]  [<ffffffff810fabdb>] ? sys_read+0x45/0x6b
[505440.365249]  [<ffffffff81036628>] ? should_resched+0x5/0x23
[505440.365251]  [<ffffffff81354d92>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[505800.364068] INFO: task sshd:21522 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[505800.365213] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[505800.366502] sshd            D ffff88006c813780     0 21522  21519 0x00000000
[505800.366506]  ffff8800677b08f0 0000000000000086 ffff880000000000 ffffffff8160d020
[505800.366508]  0000000000013780 ffff880037275fd8 ffff880037275fd8 ffff8800677b08f0
[505800.366510]  0000000000000246 ffffffff8134fd89 ffff88006cbd6460 ffff88003cb91748
[505800.366513] Call Trace:
[505800.366520]  [<ffffffff8134fd89>] ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x9/0x25
[505800.366528]  [<ffffffffa0098660>] ? do_get_write_access+0x1ad/0x36a [jbd2]
[505800.366532]  [<ffffffff8105fcfd>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x2a/0x2a
[505800.366535]  [<ffffffff8110cf1d>] ? inode_init_always+0xfa/0x1aa
[505800.366538]  [<ffffffffa0098911>] ? jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x21/0x38 [jbd2]
[505800.366545]  [<ffffffffa00d1263>] ? __ext4_journal_get_write_access+0x4f/0x5e [ext4]
[505800.366549]  [<ffffffffa00aaf59>] ? ext4_new_inode+0x418/0xc6b [ext4]
[505800.366552]  [<ffffffffa009779c>] ? jbd2__journal_start+0x8a/0xce [jbd2]
[505800.366556]  [<ffffffffa00b4e1e>] ? ext4_mknod+0x77/0x13a [ext4]
[505800.366561]  [<ffffffffa00c66d8>] ? ext4_journal_start_sb+0x139/0x14f [ext4]
[505800.366564]  [<ffffffff8113bfa2>] ? __dquot_initialize+0x1d/0xfe
[505800.366568]  [<ffffffffa00b4e5f>] ? ext4_mknod+0xb8/0x13a [ext4]
[505800.366571]  [<ffffffff8110498d>] ? vfs_mknod+0x9c/0xbe
[505800.366573]  [<ffffffff81036628>] ? should_resched+0x5/0x23
[505800.366576]  [<ffffffff812f9f7b>] ? unix_bind+0x15a/0x2b4
[505800.366591]  [<ffffffff8128074d>] ? sys_bind+0x75/0xad
[505800.366594]  [<ffffffff81280532>] ? sys_socket+0x39/0x57
[505800.366596]  [<ffffffff81354d92>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[505800.366598] INFO: task mktemp:21529 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[505800.367748] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[505800.369024] mktemp          D ffff88006c813780     0 21529  21528 0x00000000
[505800.369027]  ffff88006754b060 0000000000000086 ffffffff00000000 ffffffff8160d020
[505800.369030]  0000000000013780 ffff880036e63fd8 ffff880036e63fd8 ffff88006754b060
[505800.369032]  0000000000000246 ffffffff8134fd89 ffff88006cbd6460 ffff88003cb91748
[505800.369034] Call Trace:
[505800.369037]  [<ffffffff8134fd89>] ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x9/0x25
[505800.369040]  [<ffffffffa0098660>] ? do_get_write_access+0x1ad/0x36a [jbd2]
[505800.369043]  [<ffffffff8105fcfd>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x2a/0x2a
[505800.369046]  [<ffffffffa0098911>] ? jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x21/0x38 [jbd2]
[505800.369051]  [<ffffffffa00d1263>] ? __ext4_journal_get_write_access+0x4f/0x5e [ext4]
[505800.369055]  [<ffffffffa00aaf59>] ? ext4_new_inode+0x418/0xc6b [ext4]
[505800.369057]  [<ffffffffa009779c>] ? jbd2__journal_start+0x8a/0xce [jbd2]
[505800.369061]  [<ffffffffa00b4f55>] ? ext4_create+0x74/0x12f [ext4]
[505800.369066]  [<ffffffffa00c66d8>] ? ext4_journal_start_sb+0x139/0x14f [ext4]
[505800.369068]  [<ffffffff8113bfa2>] ? __dquot_initialize+0x1d/0xfe
[505800.369072]  [<ffffffffa00b4f97>] ? ext4_create+0xb6/0x12f [ext4]
[505800.369074]  [<ffffffff81104a15>] ? vfs_create+0x66/0x88
[505800.369076]  [<ffffffff81102a2d>] ? d_alloc_and_lookup+0x3a/0x60
[505800.369078]  [<ffffffff81105459>] ? do_last+0x25b/0x58d
[505800.369080]  [<ffffffff81105d83>] ? path_openat+0xce/0x33a
[505800.369083]  [<ffffffff810ce865>] ? pte_offset_kernel+0x16/0x35
[505800.369085]  [<ffffffff811060b1>] ? do_filp_open+0x2a/0x6e
[505800.369087]  [<ffffffff8134ea6c>] ? _cond_resched+0x7/0x1c
[505800.369090]  [<ffffffff811b4589>] ? __strncpy_from_user+0x18/0x48
[505800.369092]  [<ffffffff8110ee37>] ? alloc_fd+0x64/0x109
[505800.369094]  [<ffffffff810fa07d>] ? do_sys_open+0x5e/0xe5
[505800.369096]  [<ffffffff81354d92>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that after 5 minutes, the Reboot Command issued via the Developer Console did do a forceful reboot of the VM, and it rebooted OK.  The Developer Console was not giving any feedback during this time, so I thought it too was hung waiting on the Hung Task to finish.